# Twitter Bootstrap Modal opening multiple backdrops, glitch in Grails

Tags: grails, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Using Grails 2.2.1, Twitter Bootstrap plugin. I'm using modals and mine are set up with 3 exit approaches. Either hit the **x** button, click a **close** button, the **save** button, OR, click anywhere outside the modal to close.

The problem is, 2 backdrops are being opened whenever I attempt to open a single modal due to the function I'm using. Why is this? With the first 3 modal closing approaches, it closes the modal, and both backdrops. But with the final approach, it just closes the modal and a single backdrop.

Here's my gsp code**sec** part is just a taglib for a security plugin I'm using):

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loginModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="loginModalLabel">Login</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="signupModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signupModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="signupModalLabel">Sign Up</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <g:link class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</g:link>
  </div>
</div>

<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
<g:javascript>
$('#loginModal').modal({
  remote: "${createLink(controller:'login', action:'auth')}",
  show: false
})
$('#signupModal').modal({
  remote: "${createLink(controller:'user', action:'create')}",
  show: false
})
</g:javascript>

<g:link fragment="loginModal" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">
Login
</g:link>
<br/>
<g:link fragment="signupModal" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">
Sign Up
</g:link>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

I tried using:

```
$('#loginModal').modal({
  remote: "${createLink(controller:'login', action:'auth')}",
  show: false
})
$('#signupModal').modal({
  remote: "${createLink(controller:'user', action:'create')}",
  show: false
})
```

But I still get 2 backdrops opening when I click on a single modal link.

This seems to be a Grails issue, because I don't get this problem with [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qHa3C/):

Comment: Not sure but I think you should try 

("#loginModel").modal('show');
I mean instead of using load try to go for modal('show'), and in it you can control backdrop.
Not sure if it can help you :)

Comment: I tried using .modal and "remote" as an option. But I"m still getting multiple backdrops opening.

Comment: Check out the jsFiddle link, it's the same code (granted I changed <g:link> to <a> but that doesn't matter cuz it renders the same) and works just fine on jsFiddle without opening 2 backdrops.

Comment: I tried it on the local, without sec tags( doesn't matter), and same code is working fine.
, I think if you use <g:include> to include login or sign up pages on the modal body and then try it out.
then it should work.

Comment: Ah... Hey guys, sorry about this. It turns out I was looping a page inside of another page (my login form via modals was a global thing) so I was getting 2 of the same modal being loaded). This was just an MVC problem, no issues with twitter modal stuffs. Sorry to waste your time :(